# LNK1136 invalid or corrupt file

Tags: c++

Trying to use .lib in Visual c++ CLR project.
This .lib is built in c++ builder 5, i have .lib file and .hpp file.

created visual c++ -> CLR -> class library project.
In properties following fields are added,
C/C++ -> General -> 
Additional include directories = C:\Users\D2\source\repos\CLR\CLR\LIB

Linker -> Additional include directories = C:\Users\D2\source\repos\CLR\CLR\LIB
Input -> Additional Dependencies = lib0.lib

C:\Users\D2\source\repos\CLR\CLR\LIB, This location contains .hpp, .lib, .dll files.

And Builded,
Linker error is coming, LNK1136 invalid or corrupt file

As this error says, I checked no other application is using this library and specified the correct library name and path. I'm confused with this corrupt file word because the same library is working with c++ builder 5.

please give suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure that C++ builder libraries *can* be used with VC++ CLR?

Comment: Old Borland tooling uses a diferent .lib file format, OMF instead of COFF, the MSVC linker does not know how to read it.  There are conversion tools around, google "convert omf to coff" to find them.  But rebuilding from source would most certainly be the better approach.

Comment: Thanks for replying,

Comment: No, i am not sure about "C++ builder libraries can be used with VC++ CLR?". and I am new to this kind of linking problems as well as OMF, COFF concepts. I don't have source code for rebuilding. Is there any other way to use this libraries, because this library is very important to me.Please give me Suggestions and time to understand this.